# Фон сайта как видео

Tags: html, css

Делаю сайт-визитку для личного пользования.
Имею одну проблему, на фоне сайта имеется 2 вертикальные полосы по бокам фона.
Не знаю, как объяснить, я новичок в этом.

css:

```
    * { box-sizing: border-box; }
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
}
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#vidtop-content {
    top: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.vid-info { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: %; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); color: #fff; padding: 1rem; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.vid-info h1 { font-size: 2rem; font-weight: 700; margin-top: 0; line-height: 1.2; }
.vid-info a { display: block; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); transition: .6s background; border-bottom: none; margin: 1rem auto; text-align: center; }
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
.vid-info { width: 50%; padding: .5rem; }
.vid-info h1 { margin-bottom: .2rem; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.vid-info .acronym { display: none; }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="video-background">
    <div class="video-foreground">
         <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RyBkBCHTGnc??controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема исправляется путем изменения следующей части кода:

```
 .video-foreground, .video-background iframe {
    left: -1px;
    width: 100.3vw;
}
```

Честно сказать, больше похоже на костыль, но работает

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: щас попробую, хм

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/exgpWMa
всё плохо

Comment: Скиньте полный код

Comment: Полный код чего?

Comment: Извините, я неправильно Вас понял. Попробуйте в тегам html и body дописать `html, body{ background: #000 }`

Answer (score 0):

Так-с, вот я и сделал видео как фон своего сайта.
Собственно, куски кода:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="video-foreground">
    <div class="video-background">
        <iframe id="ytplayer" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N2Y2vQ-1m7M?disablekb=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=N2Y2vQ-1m7M" frameborder="0" loop="loop" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Изменить видео: изменить "**N2Y2vQ-1m7M**" на другой идентификатор в начале ссылки, и в конце, тобишь, где плейлист указан.

**CSS:**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
```

Изменить непрозрачность: "opacity: **"число до 1"**;"

**JS:**

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '1080',
      width: '1920',
      videoId: 'N2Y2vQ-1m7M'
    });
  }
```

Тут также необходимо изменить "**N2Y2vQ-1m7M**" на свой идентификатор.